# motion_planning_rviz_plugin "segmentation fault"

Tags: ros, rviz, rviz-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi eveyone,

I'm doing DisplayingRobotTrajectoriesInRviz tutorial and in the last step, when I'm configuring the Planning display type (whit  topic name: joint_path_display and robot_description field: robot_description) the aplication crash: Segmentation fail.

I'm use ros Fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04

Any body know what can I do??

Redards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45397/motion_planning_rviz_plugin-%22segmentation-fault%22/) by [Sanxano](https://answers.ros.org/users/1103/sanxano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2012-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In electric and Ubuntu 11.10 doesn't work either.

---

Originally posted by [Sanxano](https://answers.ros.org/users/1103/sanxano/) with karma: 70 on 2012-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0